# Any reason why this CSS Accordion wouldn't work in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

After fixing the HTML that calls it from being mangled by the website I was using it on, I at least managed to get the closed states to display properly. However the slides won't open at all. Here's the CSS:

```
/**
 *  CSS3 Only Horizontal and Vertical Accordion
 *  Author: Paul Underwood for Hongkiat.com
 *  Website: www.paulund.co.uk
 *  Date: 27/11/11
 *  Version: 1.0
 */


article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { display: block; }
audio, canvas, video { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
[hidden] { display: none; }
html { font-size: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.231; }
body, button, input, select, textarea { font-family: sans-serif; color: #222; }

/*Define Accordion box*/
.accordion { width:700px; overflow:hidden; margin:10px auto; color:#474747; background:#414141; padding:10px; }

/*General Accordion****************************************************************************/
/*Set style of open slide*/
.accordion section:target { background:#FFF; padding:10px;}
.accordion section:target:hover { background:#FFF; }
.accordion section:target h2 {width:100%;}
.accordion section:target h2 a{ color:#333; padding:0;}
.accordion section:target p {display:block;}
.accordion section h2 a{padding:8px 10px;display:block; font-size:16px; font-weight:normal;color:#eee; text-decoration:none; }

/*set style of closed slide*/
.accordion section{ float:left; overflow:hidden; color:#139fec; cursor:pointer; background: #139fec; margin:3px; }
.accordion section:hover {background:#7fc5ec;}
.accordion section p { display:none; }
.accordion section:after{position:relative;font-size:24px;color:#000;font-weight:bold;}
.accordion section:nth-child(1):after{content:'1';}
.accordion section:nth-child(2):after{content:'2';}
.accordion section:nth-child(3):after{content:'3';}
.accordion section:nth-child(4):after{content:'4';}
.accordion section:nth-child(5):after{content:'5';}
/*End General Accordion****************************************************************************/

/*Horizontal Accordion *********************************************************************/
.horizontal section{ width:5%; height:250px; 
    -moz-transition:width 0.2s ease-out; 
    -webkit-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
}

/*Position the number of the slide*/
.horizontal section:after{top:140px;left:15px;}

/*Header of closed slide*/
.horizontal section h2 { 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width:240px; position:relative; left:-100px; top:85px;
} 

/*On mouse over open slide*/
.horizontal :target{ width:73%;height:230px; }
.horizontal :target h2{ top:0px;left:0;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg); 
}
/*End Horizontal Accordion *********************************************************************/

/*Vertical Accordion *************************************************************************/
.vertical section{ width:100%; height:40px;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
}
/*Set height of the slide*/
.vertical :target{ height:250px; width:97%; }

.vertical section h2 { position:relative; left:0; top:-15px; }

/*Set position of the number on the slide*/
.vertical section:after{ top:-60px;left:810px;}
.vertical section:target:after{ left:-9999px;}

.accordion img{
    display:inline-block;
    width:211px;
    height:146px;
    border:1px solid white;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.accordion div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:311px;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.tumblr.com/fq90l5c/7mhmmh2t0/style.css" /> 
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/fq90l5c/2Csmn937d/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="accordion vertical"><section id="vertabout">
<h2><a href="#vertabout">Tutor-Led Course</a></h2>
<img src="image" height="146" width="211" />
<div>To view the tutor-led course information, please click <a href="link">here</a></div>
</section><section id="vertservices">
<h2><a href="#vertservices">E-Learning Module</a></h2>
<img src="image" height="146" width="211" />
<div>To view the E-Learning course information, please click <a href="link">here</a></div>
</section></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see why this wouldn't work in IE8? I've tested it with Firefox, where it works just fine.

Comment: why you dont use jquery?this supported all browser

Comment: @mehdi hm, let me think ... `CSS3 Only Horizontal and Vertical Accordion`...

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anth-child would be one really good reason this can't work in IE8 without shimming.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that the `:target` pseudoclass is only supported in IE9+. Another issue that would affect the display is that those transitions won't render in IE8, but, again, this probably only affects how nicely the accordion works as opposed to being the cause for it not working at all.

Source for target support: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget#Browser_compatibility)

Source for transition support: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Actually, there are many properties which doesn't work in IE8 like `transform`, `transition`. and not to mention those `HTML 5` tags.

Comment: Good points, @Mr_Green. After seeing the `:target` pseudoclass and seeing that it seemed pretty critical to the functioning of the accordion, I stopped my search there. I should have kept looking!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies, would the html5shiv in there not deal with the HTML5 tag/properties problems?

Comment: @jmeas, he's already using `html5shiv.js`, the problem here is the lack of support for CSS selectors in IE8.

Comment: And as always, http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anth-child is a go-to resource when trying to figure out if some feature is or is not supported by a given browser!

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selectors :target and :nth-child aren't supported by IE8. You can add support for IE8 users with a polyfill (much like you add support for HTML5 through `html5shiv.js`).

I often *(read: always)* include [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) in my projects to create support for such selectors in IE6-8.

Comment: and what about the `css3` properties?

Comment: Either use filters [(documentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#10) or javascript to solve the transitions and transforms.

Comment: Okay, basically it looks like I should just find another source for the Accordion in general, rather than just applying continuous work-arounds. My CSS/HTML skills just arn't up to scratch for this I think :)

Comment: Not necessarily. Include `selectivizr.js` through a conditional comment, just like you're doing with `html5shiv.js`. Adding support for older browsers isn't "workarounds" from my point of view. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately on the selectivizr website I found this stipulation: "Style sheets MUST be hosted on the same domain as the page due to browser security restrictions. Likewise, style sheets loaded using the file: protocol will not work." It's not possible for me to host the styyle sheets on the page/site. So I don't think it'll work for me.